# Datadog Monitor to alert when AWS lambda function not invoked within certain time?

Tags: datadog

I am trying to create a data dog monitor that will alert whenever a specific lambda function has not been invoked within 1 hours. This needs to happen at a scheduled basis and if it has not happened I need an alert.

I have tried to create several monitor queries but it is not working.

My metric query looks like

```
sum:aws.lambda.invocations{resource:my-lambda-function}.as_count()
```

These are my alert conditions

[image]

I then don't invoke the lambda function as necessary within the 1 hour. Then after the 1 hour passes the monitor never alerts. I think it's because it's not getting any data?

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to create a monitor on invocations with some arbitrary threshold; the alert conditions don't really matter, what matters is that the monitor is configured to `Notify` on [no data](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/create/configuration/?tab=thresholdalert#no-data). Set the time threshold to 60 minutes.

[image: screenshot of alert conditions]

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing. I don't think it's the right approach though - we have hundreds of monitors and many have "no-data" and we mostly pay attention to those that are in an Alarm state.

Comment: Let me see if I can find any better ways. I agree it's a bit hacky, especially if you already have noise on that indicator